# Sonar 5.3-1 giving elastic search error

Tags: elasticsearch, sonarqube, centos7, sonarqube-ops

I have an instance of Sonarqube which on startup gives this exception:

Full logs available here: [Sonar.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/djzzctdoilvdzcn/sonar.log?dl=0)

Comment: Is it a fresh install, an upgrade or a startup of an existing installation ?

Comment: this is a startup of an existing installation.

Comment: do you know any operational changes done since the last shutdown ? Do you have the logs of previous startup/shutdown ?

Comment: No operational changes were made both at the os level and from within the app. The sever shut down abruptly however before this

Comment: added sonar.log

Comment: the logs do not relate to version 5.3 but to 6.0. Please clarify what is being done.

Comment: That is weird. I have just checked and the yum version is listed as 5.3-1.

Comment: There seems to have been an upgrade that was rolled back. How can I proceed at this point? Can I recover this version or do I have to upgrade?

Comment: You should restore the backup of DB 5.3 and start a 5.3 instance to ensure that everything is correct. Then feel free to upgrade if you want to.